# Relativistic conservation of momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, energy-conservation

In section **16-4 Relativistic mass** of *The Feynman Lectures on Physics* [relativistic mass](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F2)  is discussed with an example of a collision between two equal mass particles.

While discussing the example from the image [16-3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F3)(a), the book mentions that the vertical velocity or $u \tan \alpha$ for *particle 2* is $w\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}$, which, correct me if I'm wrong, should be the vertical velocity for *particle 2* seen from a stationary observer. Thus the change in momentum seen from a stationary point of view for *particle 2* is $\Delta p' = 2m_v w\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}$, which is later compared to $\Delta p = 2m_ww$, which, correct me if I'm wrong, is the change in momentum of *particle 1* seen from the viewer moving at the same horizontal velocity as *particle 1*.

If all stated above is correct, how is it possible to compare the change in momentum of the stationary scenario with the change in momentum of the scenario where the observer is moving with the velocity of *particle 1*? Aren't you supposed to pick one frame on which to execute all conservation of momentum comparisons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking how it's possible to compare two quantities that are different? Isn't that the point of comparison? The momentums should be different in different frames, only certain scalar quantities are "frame invariant", these are called "lorentz invariant" quantities

Comment: How are you defining the "momentum of a frame"?

Comment: Distinguish between particles and frames. In a collision between two particles, there are **four** rest frames: comoving with 1 before collision, comoving with 1 after collision, comoving with 2 before collision, comoving with 2 after collision.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of the two observers' frame of reference; they are symmetric.

Each observer sees two equal particles: one particle is moving slowly vertically (speed $w$) but not at all horizontally, the other particle is moving even slower vertically (speed $w\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$) but very fast horizontally (speed $u$).

Choose the frame of any one of the two observers. In that frame the two particles collide in such a way that only their vertical velocity components are affected. Since it's an elastic collision, and by symmetry, the vertical velocity components just change sign. The two particles must therefore have equal (but opposite directed) vertical components of the momentum.

Thus,
$p_{\text{vertical, fast-moving}} = p_{\text{vertical, slow-moving}} = m_{\text{slow-moving}} w.$
Assuming that momentum also for high speeds is mass times velocity, i.e. $p_{\text{vertical, fast-moving}} = m_{\text{fast-moving}} w\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ we get that
$$
m_{\text{fast-moving}} = \frac{m_{\text{slow-moving}}}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! There is one think I still don't quite understand though. Why is the the vertical velocity of *particle 2* in the example [16-3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F3)(a) $w\sqrt{1−u2/c2}$ instead of $w$ (like the velocity from *particle 1*)? Both particles should be moving with equal vertical velocity no matter what the velocity of the observer is, right?

Comment: In the frame of observer 1 (the stationary observer) particle 1 moves with vertical speed $w.$ Likewise, in the frame of observer 2 (moving horizontally with speed $u$) particle 2 moves with vertical speed $w.$ But because of time dilation, the time it takes for particle 2 to pass a certain vertical distance $L,$ which is equal in both frames, is longer in the frame of observer 1 than in the frame of observer 2, $(L/w)/\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2},$ which means that speed is slower, $w\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}.$

Comment: Why isn't for both particles the same though? I understand that the vertical velocity is slower for in *observer 2* because of time dilation. But why is particle 1's vertical velocity $w$ and particles 2's vertical velocity $w\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}$ for *observer 2*? Shouldn't both be  $w\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}$?

Comment: The setup of this _Gedankenexperiment_ is that particle 1 has vertical speed $w$ in the frame of observer 1 and particle 2 has vertical speed $w$ in the frame of observer 2.

Comment: Actually the speed for the particles for *observer 1* is never mentioned on the section, right? The only thing that we know is that for *observer 2 particle 1*  is moving with vertical speed $w$. Why isn't *particle 2* moving with that same verrtical speed then?
Also remember that momentum is $0$ in scenario [16-2](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F2)(b) so that means that both particles must have the same vertical speed for *observer 1*. I don't understand why that isn't the case for *observer 2* then.

Comment: I haven't actually read the text you referred to. I just know the standard setup from when I studied special relativity 35 years ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150352/discussion-between-erp-and-md2perpe).